# Testing and design fee for MFi devices

Tags: iphone, device, mfi

We want to obtain MFi certificate and make products work with iPhone/iPad.

@Brad Larson gave a very good answer to MFi application. But I need some more specific answer. 
[Looking for experiences on the Apple MFi program registration process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734071/looking-for-experiences-on-the-apple-mfi-program-registration-process)

1. How much is the testing fee paid to a 3rd-party?
2. Does the mentioned "20,000$ ~ 80,000$ design fee" include the testing fee in question 1?
3. Does the design fee necessary or can we do design all by ourselves?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remember that anyone who has signed up to the MFi program will have signed an NDA and thus won't be able to tell you anything.